# Service Worker caching resources with Flask Blueprints

Tags: flask, service-worker

I am using `Flask` as a web framework. I have defined an `html` resource within my service worker definition like below

```
var urlsToPrefetch = [
    'webapp/templates/practice/foopage.html',
];
```

This works ok.

Using `Flask Blueprints`, `foopage.html` is rendered to the user when they visit `https://example.com/practice/foopage`. The `Blueprint` name is "practice".

The corresponding route is below:

```
@practice.route('/foopage', methods=['GET'])
def foopage():
    return render_template('practice/foopage.html')
```

The problem is that within the service worker's `fetch` eventListener shows the `event.request.url` as `https://example.com/practice/foopage`

This is not found in the cache because I had to define the `html` file using its actual path.

Is there a way to map filenames to the routes used in the application? Or do I need to think about this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing paths to templates, which is a server side thing, with urls that get routed to views.  As far as the client can tell, the response from `/foopage` is the document, it doesn't matter how that document was generated on the server side.

Specify the url to the resource, `/foopage`, as the thing to prefetch.